# upload image into image actvex control from binary type in vba excel

Tags: excel, vba

Currently now I'm working in VBA Excel and I'm trying to import the image (.png) from the sql server. I have completely done to insert the image into sql server in binary type. This is the sql query that i have done.

***INSERT INTO [DemoDatabase].[dbo].[well_image] ([well_img])
SELECT BulkColumn
FROM openrowset ( Bulk 'C:\Users\Pictures\003.png', Single_Blob) as img***

Then I'm try to select the fetch the image from the sql server and display it in **image activex control** but it give me an error.

run time error, object required. (the error)

Below I'm provide the code for your overview.

```
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
Set stm = New ADODB.Stream

Dim sqlquery As String

sqlquery = "SELECT [well_img] FROM well_image WHERE [img_id] = 2"

rs.Open sqlquery, objConnection, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic

stm.Type = adTypeBinary
stm.Open
stm.Write rs("well_img").Value   'write bytes to stream
stm.Position = 0

'Sheet1.OLEObjects("well_img").Object.Picture = stm.Read 'load bytes into image control on form
 Sheet1.well_img.Picture = stm.Read    ***here is the problem

stm.Close
rs.Close
objConnection.Close
```

when I'm debug, this line is the problem "Sheet1.well_img.Picture = stm.Read".
I need your help. Please help me and thank u for your consideration.

Comment: I'm not sure about this, but have you tried `Set Sheet1.well_img.Picture = stm.Read`

Comment: Try creating the file from the bytestream in a temporary location (or you can kill the file after you're done) and then using the `.LoadPicture` method on the shape object.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really have a solution for you, but I don't believe you can load a picture this way. From [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa443228%28v=vs.60%29.aspx):

> Note   At run time, the Picture property can be set to any other
>   object's DragIcon, Icon, Image, or Picture property, or you can assign
>   it the graphic returned by the LoadPicture function. The exception to
>   this is the Picture property of the ListImages object, which is a
>   read-only property.

The [LoadPicture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa172231%28v=office.11%29.aspx) function takes a filepath as an argument as well. This article explains [how to store and load images from an Access database](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/store-images-in-a-database-HP005280225.aspx). Unfortunately, none of this solves your problem, but I hope it may tell you why it can't be done the way you're trying to do it.

Comment: Thanks to all of u about the suggestion and opinion about this problem. I will try another way and hopefully it's work. And if anything improvement i will let you know. Thanks again.

Comment: Please do. We're a Q & A community, so it's completely acceptable to answer your own question. And who knows, maybe someone will come along with a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late reply. I have try the solution that all of u given, but still does not work. Then I try to use another way to do it. Even though this is not answer the question but I just want to share what I'm already done.

---

Now I set the image data type as string/varchar. This is because I plan to save the image name and the image itself is save to a specific folder that I set. This is the way how I'm do it.

The code

---

```
Dim imgDir as String, imgName as String
imgDir = "C:\Users\pc\Pictures\img\"
imgName = "test.jpg"

'copy img from source directory to destination directory
Dim destinationImg As String
destinationImg = "C:\Users\pc\Pictures\img\" & imgName

'FileCopy is a method that copy file to specific folder/directory
FileCopy imgDir, destinationImg   

'-----------------
'insert imgName to database
'set up connection
Call serverConn

Dim sqlquery As String
sqlquery = "INSERT INTO well_img ([img_name]) " & _
           "VALUES ('" & imgName & "') "

objConnection.Execute sqlquery

' close connection
objConnection.Close
Set objConnection = Nothing
```

---

And this is the way I display the image. I use image activeX control.

```
Dim destinationImg As String
destinationImg = "C:\Users\pc\Pictures\img\" & imgName

Sheet2.dwnload_img.Picture = LoadPicture(destinationImg)
```

That all from me. Any improvement are welcome and thank u everyone. :)